# bookmarking group of vertices in 3ds max (for easily select)

Tags: 3ds-max

I want to make group of vertices for easily select vertices,like "add selected vertices to group" in blender
I want to bookmark Vertex groups in3dsmax ,like this : (this is define in blender ,I have no idea what it called in 3dsmax.

> Vertex groups identify sub-components of a mesh, like the legs of a
>   chair or the hinges of a door. By “bookmarking” such regions in vertex
>   groups you can easily select and work on them in isolation without
>   having to create separate objects.

so i'm asking for similar method in 3dsmax.
Please tell me how to do it
Thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

You can save a selection set. On the main toolbar, there is a `Create selection set`.

[image: Selection sets]

With the object selected and in vertex mode you just type in the name of your selection of vertices. Later you can load the selection by selecting the set from the same menu (you must be in vertex mode in the mesh, otherwise the sets work as groups of objects).

Comment: Hi t17dr, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!